# Kubernetes - How to acces to service from a web server in pod with a rest request

Tags: kubernetes

I'm looking to use Kubernetes DNS to requetes pods from pods. All is in my Kubernetes cluster.

I would like to use a http requeste from a web app to call another web app

For exemple I would like to call ProductWebApp from DashboardWebApp

I found kubernetes rest api

➜  ~ kubectl exec -it dashboard-57f598dd76-54s2x -- /bin/bash

➜  ~ curl -X GET https://4B3449144A41F5488D670E69D41222D.sk1.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com/api/v1/namespaces/staging/services/product-app/proxy/api/product/5bf42b2ca5fc050616640dc6 
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "services \"product-app\" is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get services/proxy in the namespace \"staging\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "name": "product-app",
    "kind": "services"
  },
  "code": 403
}%

I don't understand why it's block

I found also this url
➜  ~ curl -XGET product-app.staging.svc.cluster.local/api/product/5bf42b2ca5fc050616640dc6

But it's also not work

So what is the good way to make a call from a pod to service ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For when *both* ProductWebApp and DashboardWebApp are running on the *same* Kubernetes cluster:

Define a Service as described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) for the app that you want to call (ProductWebApp) using `type: ClusterIP` service; configure the calling app (DashboardWebApp) with the service name as the URI to call.

For example, assuming ProductWebApp is in a namespace named `staging`, define a service named `product-app` for the ProductWebApp deployment and then configure the DashboardWebApp to call ProductWebApp at this URI:

```
http://product-app.staging.svc.cluster.local/end/point/as/needed
```

Replace http with https if the ProductWebApp endpoint requires it. Notice that a Service name can be the same as the name of the Deployment for which the service is.

This works when the Kubernetes cluster is running a DNS service (and most clusters do) - see this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) and specifically the [A records](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#a-records) section.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the similar issue

Tries above solution for providing the

http://*service-name*.*namespace*.svc.cluster.local:*port-number*

This usually works on reaching from one pod to another , but this fails when there is security applies on the pod which you try to reach .

Here I stuck on the same , So you can create a service account in the pod which you try to reach :

*service-account.yaml*

apiVersion: v1

kind: ServiceAccount

metadata:

```
name: {{ template "kafka-schema-registry.fullname" . }}
```

An write a auth-policy to allow that service account :

*auth-policy.yaml*

{{- if .Values.auth.enabled -}}

apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1

kind: AuthorizationPolicy

metadata:

name: {{ template "*pod-name*.fullname" . }}

spec:

selector:

```
matchLabels:

  app: {{ template "*pod-name*.name" . }}
```

action: ALLOW

rules:

- from:

  - source:

    principals: ["cluster.local/ns/*name-space*/sa/*pod-name*"]

  to:

  - operation:

    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT"]

After all the above changes done on above pod which you try to reach from another pods.

the other pods just needs to provide the service account name in the *deployment.yaml*

example as below :

*deployment.yaml*

apiVersion: apps/v1

kind: Deployment

metadata:

name: {{ .Values.name }}

namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}

labels:

```
app: {{ .Values.name }}
```

spec:

replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}

selector:

```
matchLabels:

  app: {{ .Values.name }}
```

template:

```
metadata:

  annotations:

    prometheus.io/scrape: "true"

    prometheus.io/path: "/actuator/prometheus"

    prometheus.io/port: {{ .Values.service.port | quote }}

  labels:

    app: {{ .Values.name }}

spec:

  serviceAccountName: {{ *pod-name* }}
```